# Oracle - Updating a Column When Changes Occur Across Multiple Tables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a scenario in my Oracle database where I have a main table A and several related tables B, C, and possibly more, joined together through complex queries. Table A has an 'update_date' column that needs to be updated whenever there's a change in any of the joined tables (B, C, etc.). Currently, I'm considering using triggers for each joined table, but I want an alternative solution instead of having as many triggers as joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want an alternative solution instead of having as many triggers as joins.

Some alternative solutions are:

1. Don't persist the `update_date` column in `table_a`.

   Instead, when you `SELECT` the value use:

   ```sql
   SELECT GREATEST(b.update_date, c.update_date, d.update_date)
   FROM   table_a a
          INNER JOIN table_b b ON (...)
          INNER JOIN table_c c ON (...)
          INNER JOIN table_d d ON (...)
   ```
2. Don't allow users to directly `UPDATE` tables `b`, `c`, `d`, etc. Have two (or more users) `table_owner`, who unsurprisingly owns the tables, and `table_viewer`, which is the user that clients connect to. Do not let clients connect directly to `table_owner`.

   Grant `table_viewer` permissions to `SELECT` from the table but do not grant them `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` persmissions. Instead create stored procedures (owned by `table_owner`) that will perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` modifications on the child tables and when the procedure makes a modification also change `table_a.update_date`, so that it is always synchronised, and then grant `EXECUTE` permissions on the stored procedure.

   Something like:

   ```sql
   CREATE PROCEDURE table_owner.update_b (
     i_id    IN table_owner.table_b.id%TYPE,
     i_value IN table_owner.table_b.value%TYPE
   )
   IS
     v_a_id IN table_owner.table_b.a_id%TYPE;
   BEGIN
     UPDATE table_owner.table_b
     SET    value = i_value
     WHERE  id = i_id
     RETURNING a_id INTO v_a_id;

     UPDATE table_owner.table_a
     SET    updated_date = SYSDATE
     WHERE  id = v_a_id;
   END;
   /

   GRANT SELECT ON table_owner.table_a TO table_viewer;
   REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table_owner.table_a FROM table_viewer;
   GRANT SELECT ON table_owner.table_b TO table_viewer;
   REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table_owner.table_b FROM table_viewer;
   GRANT EXECUTE ON table_owner.update_b TO table_viewer;
   ```

Comment: the problem is that only table 'A' has update_date column

Comment: @sabaartkmeladze Option #2 would still work for that case.